# Is it possible to create a custom themes in Anycharts Qlik extension

Tags: qliksense, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm looking to this documentation, I've already download the anychart extension but I cannot find these files (or even the "lib" folder mentioned) in either a desktop or enterprise installation.

https://www.anychart.com/blog/2019/01/16/qlik-data-visualization-custom-drawing/

Is there anyone found these files/folders? or successfully created a custom theme for the Anycharts qlikSense extension?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done the custom theming with Anychart but regarding the paths ...

- QS Enterprise

  Once an extension is uploaded to Qlik it is stored into the static content folder.
  [image: static content folder]

  You'll have to access this network path and navigate to the extensions folder, find your extension and add the files there

  [image: network path]
- QS Desktop
  The path shown onto Anychart page seems correct to me. If the installation is done in the normal way. In the enterprise world i've seen that some companies are installing QS Desktop in different path. So if you are using QS Desktop in a company environment it is possible that the `Qlik` folder is located somewhere else (and not under `c:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\`